# Setting URL resource values in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am trying to convert Apple's ["ShapeEdit"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ShapeEdit/Introduction/Intro.html) example to Swift 3, and I cannot get my head round the changes to `URL`'s `setResourceValue`.

The Apple (Swift 2) example has this code:

```
// Coordinate reading on the source path and writing on the destination path to copy.
let readIntent = NSFileAccessIntent.readingIntentWithURL(templateURL, options: [])
let writeIntent = NSFileAccessIntent.writingIntentWithURL(target, options: .ForReplacing)

NSFileCoordinator().coordinateAccessWithIntents([readIntent, writeIntent], queue: self.coordinationQueue) { error in
    if error != nil { return }
    do {
        try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(readIntent.URL, toURL: writeIntent.URL)    
        try writeIntent.URL.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLHasHiddenExtensionKey)    
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self.openDocumentAtURL(writeIntent.URL)
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unexpected error during trivial file operations: \(error)")
    }
}
```

`setResourceValue(value: forKey:)` seems to have been replaced by `setResourceValues()`, but I cannot set it. What I have so far is this:

```
let readIntent = NSFileAccessIntent.readingIntent(with: templateURL, options: [])
let writeIntent = NSFileAccessIntent.writingIntent(with: target, options: .forReplacing)

NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(with: [readIntent, writeIntent], queue: self.coordinationQueue) { error in
    if error != nil { return }                
    do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(at: readIntent.url, to: writeIntent.url)
        var resourceValues: URLResourceValues = URLResourceValues.init()
        resourceValues.hasHiddenExtension = true
        // *** Error on next line ***
        try writeIntent.url.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
        // Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'url' is a get-only property

        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            self.openDocumentAtURL(writeIntent.URL)
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unexpected error during trivial file operations: \(error)")
    }      
}
```

I can find no documentation other than the Xcode "jump to definition", which says

> Sets the resource value identified by a given resource key.
>
> This method writes the new resource values out to the backing store. Attempts to set a read-only resource property or to set a resource property not supported by the resource are ignored and are not considered errors. This method is currently applicable only to URLs for file system resources.
>
> `URLResourceValues` keeps track of which of its properties have been set. Those values are the ones used by this function to
>   determine which properties to write.
>
> `public mutating func setResourceValues(_ values: URLResourceValues) throws`

Does anyone have any insight into the changes to `setResourceValue(s)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current declaration of `NSFileAccessIntent.URL` is

```
public var url: URL { get }
```

It's a read-only property.

Since Swift 3 `URL` is a `struct`, therefore you cannot call mutating methods on  the immutable value that is returned from the getter. To modify the URL first assign it to a `var`.

```
var url = intent.URL
url.setResourceValues(...)
```

And then create a new intent from the modified URL.

Comment: When learning new stuff, one assumes one's error is there, and not in the old stuff! You're nearly right, but the `intent.url` is still read-only, so your third line doesn't work. But the idea's right - re-initialising the intent with the modified URL works - `intent = NSFileAccessIntent.writingIntent(with: url, options: .forReplacing)`. Do you want to update the answer, or shall I?

Comment: Maybe place your own answer instead and I will delete this one :)

Comment: It took me a while get to the current documentation.

Comment: be sure define the url use var not let

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is helpful, but working code is even better

```
do {
    var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
    resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
    try fileUrl.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
} catch _{
}
```

As @Sulthan mentioned, fileURL must be mutable.